# Creating a select with knockout-classBindingProvider

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using the knockout 'plugin' which can be found here:

https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-classBindingProvider

here is the official "demo" for the tool with a select list that I added:
http://jsfiddle.net/LvwRt/26/

This is the Item object which has two properties:

```
var Item = function(name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(name);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
};
```

This knockout viewmodel:

```
var ViewModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;

    this.editable = ko.observable(true);

    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.addItem = function() {
        self.items.push(new Item("New"));
    };

    this.deleteItem = function(item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([
    new Item("Pen"),
    new Item("Pencil"),
    new Item("Eraser")
]), document.getElementById("content"));
```

the select dom element:

```
<select data-class="selectItem"></select>
```

The selectItem binding:

```
    selectItem: function(context) {
        return {
            options: context.$root.items, 
            value: name, 
            optionsText: 'name'
        }
    }
```

Now the above code works as you would expect. Knockout keeps tracks of the items and everything updates correctly.

However, if I change the select binding to

```
    selectItem: function(context) {
        return {
            options: context.$root.items, 
            value: id, 
            optionsText: 'name'
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
```

Here is a link to the broken code.
http://jsfiddle.net/LvwRt/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `id` with `this.id`:

```
return {
    options: context.$root.items, 
    value: this.id, 
    optionsText: 'name'
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d98YE/).

Comment: Actually, it just happened to work with it: `name` variable isn't defined in this function, so it should have been an error too. But JSFiddle is set up so that the frame with the results of execution has a name (`'result'`).